# JSR-236 Concurrency Utilities support in JBoss EAP

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, jboss

Does anyone know if the Enterprise version of JBoss supports the concurrent utilities defined in JSR-236 and, if not, whether there is any roadmap for their support?

I couldn't find any info online and the only related RH knowledge base post is not accessible without a paid subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss EAP 7 does support the JSR-236 Concurrency Utilities. As far as I know this is the first release that supports them.